# How to get android's native methods source code

Tags: android, native, android-source

Is it possible to get and watch at Android's program component's native methods code. If anyone knows how to, please let me know.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can find source code for Android native methods using <strike>[Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch#/&exact_package=android)</strike> one of the following services:

- [AndroidXRef](http://androidxref.com/)
- [GitHub](https://github.com/search) (using `repo:android/*` search term)

The search for "[SystemClock || android*SystemClock](http://androidxref.com/source/search?project=frameworks&path=SystemClock+%7C%7C+android*SystemClock)" in AndroidXref will point you to the [`android_os_SystemClock.cpp`](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_SystemClock.cpp) file which in turn forwards many of its methods to [SystemClock.cpp](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/native/libs/utils/SystemClock.cpp)

Other Android `.cpp` or `.h` files with native methods implementations could be found in a similar way.

Comment: As of Jan 2012, the Code search site has been taken down.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for android SDK code then you can find it here:
https://android.googlesource.com

Comment: Actually I want to look at SystemClock.java and it's native method implementation, do you know in what folder can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

https://android.googlesource.com

git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base

For Google application look at `platform/packages/apps/[APP name]`

Answer (score -1):

Beside the [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/) you can find the code just by using google, e.g. search for:

```
android SystemClock source code
```

I got links to [grepcode (SystemClock)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/os/SystemClock.java). I find it more compfortable to browse the code here (be careful which version of code you are browsing).

Comment: Yeah, I know grepcode, but I also need native methods implementations