# Getting Access on the Android VideoView received packets when Streaming a URL

Tags: java, android, video-streaming, native, android-videoview

Does the native code of the VideoView give access to the received packets of the video before or after decoding it? I need to access these packets in order to transmit them to another device. The initial solution is to modify the Android native code. Other possible solutions that I found are to use GStreamer or FFmpeg libraries. 
I need bit guidance in order to achieve that goal.

Assume the phone is rooted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, not that I know of.

Long answer is that you haven't given enough detail. What data exactly do you need access to? Are you writing an application, or modifying your OS to do this to other applications?

The code that actually fetches a remote video is in `MediaPlayer` and is native. See the following method in `MediaPlayer`:

```
private void setDataSource(/* snip */) throws /* snip */ {
    /* snip */
    else if (scheme != null) {
        // handle non-file sources
        nativeSetDataSource(
            MediaHTTPService.createHttpServiceBinderIfNecessary(path),
            path,
            keys,
            values);
        return;
    }
    /* snip */
```

Unfortunately for you, almost all of the relevant `MediaPlayer` code is `native`, and if not, it is private (so subclassing will not work here).

However, depending on what you need to do, you could possibly override `VideoView` method `setVideoURI(Uri, Map<String, String>)`, which is public. Here you can grab the URI and then proxy it through your own web service, or something. This isn't quite what you were asking, though.

Or, you could possibly look into modifying the `Surface` that is drawn to by `MediaPlayer`. Most of the relevant code is still `native` though.

The final possibility that I'll mention (there are probably hundreds of possible approaches) would be to modify the `MediaHTTPService` class. This appears to be used by `MediaPlayer`, but I can't be sure because if it's used, it's used in native code.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804674/how-to-get-androids-native-methods-source-code) recommends finding the native code at [androidxref.com](http://androidxref.com/)

Edit:

As requested, here is a little more detail about what the "proxy server" solution might look like. I don't know the implementation details on Android.

Basically, when you get a URL to play in the `VideoView`, you pass it to your own server instead.  Something like `startProxyServer(videoUrl)`. This starts a server, which downloads and then re-hosts the video.  To get this working locally, start a webserver listening on `localhost`.  The server just downloads the video at `videoUrl`, saves it locally, and then hosts it at `localhost:port/?video=${videoUrl}`.

So in very high-level pseudo-code the server could look like.

```
public void startProxyServer(String videoUrl) {
  int PORT = 28641; // random port
  File f = downloadFile(videoUrl);
  saveFile(f, '/path/to/server/storage');
  startWebServer('localhost', PORT);
}
```

So now you give `localhost:port/?video=${videoUrl}` as url to the `videoView` instead.  Also, now other `videoView` instances can download from that same localhost url.

To make it work with other phones, your server of course couldn't run on `localhost`.
Of course I've not implemented this, but it's just one solution I can think of.

Comment: What I am trying to do is the following:
The App is streaming a video from the server and at the same time it is acting as a server that is streaming the same video to other clients. So I thought, I can modify the existing methods that stream a video on Android by adding some code to let the App forward the packets of the video while streaming it. This method requires the least amount of coding since the streaming and video displaying is already done. So forwarding the packet is the only thing left.
Note: I have no problem with modifying the Native code or re-compiling the whole OS.

Comment: Then you can check the [native code](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libmedia/IMediaHTTPService.cpp) for `HTTPMediaService`.   It might be easier to simply implement a proxy server to stream & buffer the file then serve it to multiple clients (including possibly localhost)

Comment: Can you please give more details about the proxy server solution? (There is a reward of 100 points of reputation for your answer)

Comment: @ZiadHalabi I added some more high level details about how it might work simply.  There are many additional layers of complexity to this (such as streaming the video download and then hosting that partially downloaded file). Sorry, but the exact details are beyond my knowledge :). Best of luck